# Where can I place the print function inside a loop/recur in Clojure?

Tags: recursion, clojure

Getting started with Clojure and functional programming.  Looking at the slow example of adding numbers in a range from the not-yet-published programming Clojure book third edition, chapter 10.

How to add a println to this loop so that I can see the values of sum as they change?

```
; performance demo only, don't write code like this 
(defn sum-to [n]
  (loop [i 1 sum 0]
    (if (<= i n)
      (recur (inc i) (+ i sum))
      sum)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`loop`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/loop) macro accepts multiple body expressions, so you can insert a side-effecting `println` expression right before your `if` expression:

```
(defn sum-to [n]
  (loop [i 1 sum 0]
    (println sum)
    (if (<= i n)
      (recur (inc i) (+ i sum)) sum)))
```

Here Clojure will use the result of the last expression in the body as the return value of the whole `loop` expression. Example:

```
(sum-to 5)
;; 0
;; 1
;; 3
;; 6
;; 10
;; 15
;;=> 15
```

Answer (score 2):

Another handy tool which in my opinions solves your problem as well but in a cleaner manner instead of printing is trace. It's extremely useful when debugging.

```
(use 'clojure.tools.trace)

  (defn sum-to
  [n]
  (loop [i 1 sum 0]
    (if (<= i n)
      (recur (inc i) (trace (+ i sum))) sum)))

(sum-to 10)
TRACE: 1
TRACE: 3
TRACE: 6
TRACE: 10
TRACE: 15
TRACE: 21
TRACE: 28
TRACE: 36
TRACE: 45
TRACE: 55
55
```

Comment: Thanks.  When searching for a solution I found many such tools and folks that wrote their own tools.  My impression was there is no tool that the community agrees on.  I've decided to suffer with print for now until I know enough to evaluate other solutions.  In any other languages I use logging packages.  I really like that trace doesn't require code change, but part of my goal is the knowing of where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but

```
  (reductions + (range 6))
```

Gives you what you’re looking for.

Comment: Yeah, see comment in my code sample of "don't write code like this"  The preferred example from the book is:  (defn best-sum-to [n] (/ (* n (inc n)) 2))

Answer (score 0):

A handy tool I often use for this purpose is the `spyx` macro [from the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#expression-debugging).

It works like so:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t] ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(defn sum-to [n]
  (loop [i 1 sum 0]
    (if (<= i n)
      (recur (inc i) (spyx (+ i sum)))
      sum)))

(spyx (sum-to 5))
```

with result:

```
(+ i sum) => 1
(+ i sum) => 3
(+ i sum) => 6
(+ i sum) => 10
(+ i sum) => 15

(sum-to 5) => 15
```

Comment: I will put Tupelo on my list of tools to evaluate